# locust.io - how to run specific amount of request every specific time

Tags: python, load, locust

I'm trying the `locust.io` (written in Python).
I'm trying to test spikes. So I've tried setting `min_wait` and `max_wait`, so it would run only within that range (every 5 minutes):

```
min_wait = 300000
max_wait = 350000
```

The problem is that it runs only 1 request each time, although I set 80 Users.

Couldn't find a way to create more requests each time.

Comment: You should provide more info, because this scenario is working fine on my PC.

Comment: what do you mean by 'working fine'? I didn't say it doesn't work. I said it sends 1 request each time it sends requests.

Comment: when using 80 users, the app will receive 80 requests (one from each locust) every 5 minutes